# Redesign my database to reduce the query execution time [SQL Server Express]

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance, sql-execution-plan

I have the following table:

```
Network_id: varchar(15) (it's an IP-Address)
mask:       tinyint     (values: 1-32)
AS:         bigint      (values: 0-400000)
```

This table has around 800,000 rows.

I have an IP Address as an input and I'm trying to figure out it belongs to which network.

I've tried many methods.

**Method one:**

I converted the structure of the table to be:

```
start_ip, end_ip
```

and wrote a stored procedure to find out if an ip address is between 2 ip addresses, then wrote another stored procedure that uses a CURSOR to iterate over the records of the table and call the first procedure and when getting a hit it breaks and return the chosen record.

This method is taking about 15-20 seconds to achieve the required, and sometimes I'm getting a time-out error before I get the result.

So, I tried method two:

**Method two**

I tried to separate the ip address into pieces x.y.z.t of type `tinyint` and tried to select a record with where condition of x, y, z, t have a specific value.

**The same time and same result**

**Method three:**

I have an idea of this method but I didn't implement it.

We can create a tree of 5 levels

- IP Address: x.y.z.t
- Level 0 to level 1: holds the x values on the edges.
- Level 1 to level 2: holds the y values on the edges.
- Level 2 to level 3: holds the z values on the edges.
- Level 3 to level 4: holds the t values on the edges.
- Level 5 leaves hold the AS number and mask inside each one.

I think this way will help me a lot but I didn't find a way to implement it in the database design.

Any other idea to be implemented in the database would be appreciated, or an idea on how to implement the third method.

Comment: Well, what indexes do you have on the table?

Comment: @OldProgrammer Can I index a column with non-unique data?

Comment: Yes, you can index non-unique data.

Comment: @OldProgrammer thanks a lot. can you post it as an answer to accept it...

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at the problem from the "network" point of view.

Define your table by using the "base" network address (32-bits for IPv4) and the "mask" that lets you know the range.

Then you could do something like (pseudocode):

```
   select networkName
     from networkDefinition n
    where (n.ip = n.mask <bitwise and> <search address>
    order by n.mask descending
```

Answer (score 0):

I designed an ip-geolocation database in sql server and was able to get great performance with a single table clustered by ip address, e.g:

```
create table ip2location (
   ip_start binary(4) not null,
   location_id int not null,
   primary key clustered (ip_start))
```

instead of having an ip_start and ip_end column, I just assume the ranges are contiguous and had a location_id for 'unknown'

looking up the location for a given ip address was lightning fast a query like this:

```
select top 1 location_id from ip2location
where ip_start <= @some_ip order by ip_start desc
```